# Creating a Custom ID (Primary Key) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have two tables(models) called `Users` and `Books` and need to create custom IDs (primary keys) values for my tables say, `u25894r` for users and `b419k` for books. I searched in the internet and stackoverflow a lot but I didn't understand WHERE I should define my custom ID generator function e.g., `AppServiceProvider boot function` or in `Model constructor` function. I'd be so appreciate it if you show the way with a little example.

**EDIT**:
I need to write functions that generate unique custom IDs for the tables.

Comment: you can set that in migration file

Comment: @MohammadAbdi how? would you please provide more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the custom id name in the Model class. Use 
`protected $primaryKey = "u25894r";` 
for user table and then make a migration.

Comment: It's a sample vlaue and my question is that where and how I should write such a ID generator function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a change in both the class/model definition (ie protected $primaryKey = "myUniqueName") and also in the migrations file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recruiters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // this is in the migration file:
        $table->id('recruiter_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set that in migration file

laravel documents is powerful for that you should read about migration from this link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work for me! I need to write a function that generates custom IDs and so that when I create for example, a user, it automatically populates the Users table primary key with the generated ID value.